# Android sqlite - select records where field is null or empty

Tags: android, sqlite

My application has an sqlite DB, where some of the fields are null or empty (meaning that I never inserted anything into that field).

I wish to select all the records for which the field is null or empty.

This is what I have tried:

```
cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, "folder_name = ? ", new String[] {"null"}, null, null, DBHelper.TIMESTAMP_COL + " DESC");
```

But that didn't work, and I didn't get any records. What do I need to do to make this work?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Try

```
cursor = db.query(DBHelper.TABLE_NAME, COLUMNS, "folder_name is null or folder_name = ?", new String[] {""}, null, null, DBHelper.TIMESTAMP_COL + " DESC");
```

Comment: none of the answers provided clarify if the "folder_name = <empty string>" is really necessary or overkill. Yours is the only one using IS NULL and the empty string check at once, so could you clarify why the double check (or if it was preventive)?

Comment: The question was how to select the records where `folder_name` is `null` or empty. I assume that `empty` is the abbreviation of `empty string`. If I would be wrong, I still would propose an preventive empty string check.

Answer (score 12):

```
db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE myColumn IS NULL", null);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use "folder_name is null"

Comment: You should provide more detail in your answer. This assumes the OP understands what you mean by that. Consider adding an example to make your answer of higher quality.

Answer (score 2):

I am using android studio 3.4,
Room   2.1.0-alpha07

**This is my Kotlin Code**
I tried using this didn't work as expected

```
`@Query("SELECT *FROM notifications WHERE status=:status OR status = null")`
```

This one is working fine

```
@Query("SELECT *FROM notifications WHERE status=:status OR status is null")
```